# name zip text file to Julian Date

Tags: zip, rename, julian-date

I have a batch file that zips text files and names it as `txtfiles-%date%.zip`. What I would like to do is change the %date% to julian date. Is this possible? I have no idea how to start. PLease help me.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe" a txtfiles-%date%.zip "*.txt"
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

have a separate batch script executing the command you gave, but instead of using %date%, use a separate variable defined prior. In this, a simple time/date conversion is possible.